# Populate class instance by enum using linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, enums, generic-list

Ive got a generic `List<Person> PersonList` which contains Persons

```
class Person 
{
    public string name  {get ; set;} 
    public string lastName  {get ; set;}
    public decimal income  {get ; set;} 
}
```

I've got a method which returns the income.

```
decimal GetPersonIncome(string name)
```

I've got enums containing the names that I want to filter:

```
enum SortednamesA
{
    george,
    jack,
    etc
}

enum SortednamesB
{
    bill,
    john,
    etc
}
```

I want to create `SortedPersonsIncome` instances based on the names of each enum.

```
Class SortedPersonsIncome 
{
    public SortedPerdons(string customListname, 
    decimal sortedPersonIncomeA,            
    decimal sortedPersonIncomeB)  
}
```

So it will go like this:

```
SortedPersonsIncome sortedA = new SortedPersonsIncome(
"newSortedPerson",
GetPersonIncome(georgeFromEnumA), 
GetPersonIncome(jackFromEnumA))
```

I want to do that with the least effort using linq or a foreach loop.
What is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I tried foreach with a nested if.

Comment: Also i tried foreach from linq and where but i am new to linq and i couldnt find a solution

Comment: Add it to the question

Comment: Why not just 

   `SortedPersonsIncome sortedA = new SortedPersonsIncome(
    "newSortedPerson",
    GetPersonIncome(SortednamesA.george.ToString()), 
    GetPersonIncome(SortednamesA.jack.ToString()))`

Comment: I use a Enum because i use specific names and i dont want any other names as input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter `PersonList` by names in your enum

```
var a = PersonList.Where(x=> Enum.GetNames(typeof(SortednamesA)).Contains(x.name))
```

`Enum.GetNames` will give you names you defined in your enum for example

`Enum.GetNames(typeof(SortednamesA)` will give you the following array `["george", "jack", "etc"]`

Comment: Very nice and elegant. Thank you.

Comment: Although a micro-optimization, this will redundantly invoke `Enum.GetNames` for each iteration of the enumerable. You can put it as a statement before the LINQ query to save the overhead